# iOS 7 UITableView: How to remove space between navigation bar and first cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7

Description of the problem: with iOS 7 in grouped `UITableView` there is a gap between the top of the table view and the first cell.

The strange part is that when I load the content for the first time the table appears to be ok (first image), but when I scroll down a space appears between top and first cell (second image):

[image] [image]

With style plain this behavior does't occur but unfortunately I need to use the grouped table view style.

Any ideas about?

Comment: Have you by chance implemented this protocol? ```- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section```

Comment: No, because I don't need the title for the section

Comment: We'll it looks like some thing like some datasource/delegate tableView issue. The other one I can possibly think of is ```- (float)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section```

Comment: I've tried to return 0 but the issue remains

Comment: Have you added any insets to the tableview/tableview's scrollview?

Comment: Sorry :( all out of ideas. (without seeing any actual code)

Comment: Have you changed anything with header (either for section or table view)? <- Such as viewForHeader... Better yet, what tableView protocol methods did you implement?

Comment: @Fry ..To set heightForHeader is 1. It's working fine
- (float)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{ 
return 1 }

Answer (score 132, accepted):

Just add this in you `ViewDidLoad` method

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer. Note: Further insets might need to be adjusted but this avoids arbitrary values.

Comment: but this breaks layout and tableview may go under navigation header.

Comment: I am also having the same issue and this solution worked for me; I have a tableView in a nib and want the main view to extend below the navigation bar, however I want the tableview (as subview) to not display the extra white space at the top of the tableview

Comment: +1 I have been trying to solve the similar issue with UITabViewController for 2 days. I am able to solve my issue with your solution. Thanks mate.

Comment: You can also set this option from Xcode , select the ViewController and from property inspector uncheck AdjustsScrollViewInsets.

Comment: But if  there is a search bar as the table view header ,then the navigation bar hides when the user clicks on the search bar and shows only when the user ends editing.Why is it so?

Comment: Because thats native, that is how it is. I hope you use UISearchController, thats why

Answer (score 37):

The answer was very funny for me and my team, and **worked like a charm**

- **In the Interface Builder, Just move the tableview under another view
  in the view hierarchy.**

**REASON:**

We observed that **this happens only for the First View in the View Hierarchy, if this first view is a UITableView**.
So, all other similar UITableViews do not have this annoying section, except the first.
We Tried moving the UITableView out of the first place in the view hierarchy, and everything was working as expected.

Comment: great solution.  i added an empty label to the view, above the table and it works.

Comment: I just went into this issue and cost me hours until I found this answer, this really helped a lot. Actually, my UITableView is in the firstplace of a UIView object, and that UIView is the root view in the XIB. I have to move something above the UITableView to resolve the issue.

Comment: THis is the only way I got it working ... Why is this happening?

Comment: What if we have the container (covering complete screen and it is below the navigation bar) which has the uitableview. Where should i put the view(or view with label)? 

Any idea? Thanks in advance guys!

Answer (score 16):

Go to the attributes inspector of the View Controller by selecting the xib or the controller in Storyboard. Uncheck the **Adjust Scroll View Insets** in **Layout**. It will solve the problem[image]

Comment: The easiest one that works! This should be the top voted :)

Answer (score 12):

If you are using a UITableView with grouped style and only 1 group, use plain style instead solve your problem.

```
UITableViewController *tableViewController;
tableViewController = [[UITableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
```

Comment: It can also be changed from the Storyboard by selecting the Table View, then changing the value under the Attributes Inspector which is found in the Utilities panel (the right side panel).

Answer (score 5):

Simplest solution to this problem in grouped type `tableView` is:

```
tableView.tableHeaderView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, self.tableView.bounds.size.width, 0.01f)];
```

Answer (score 3):

For solve this problem make sure that you unchecked this field on ViewController:

On ViewController >> Attibutes Inspector >> Layout (unchecked - **Adjust Scroll View Insets**)

[image]

if this is not enough, try this on TableView, set Style to **Plain**:

[image: Example image]

This will solve your problem

Comment: wow second item helped for me. knocking my head on the table for not thinking of this

Answer (score 2):

guys!
I had the same problem. TableView appeared with free space between nav bar and first cell.
This code saved me:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section == 0) {
        return 10;
    }
    else return 2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There was a space above the UITableView itself, and also between the cells.
Found my solution in 2 different answers above..posting it again so that nobody misses both solutions.

This removed the space from above :

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
```

and this removed the spaces below the cells :
Setting the 'Style' attribute of the UITableView to 'Plain'

Answer (score 1):

I am working with `Xcode 7.3.1`, `iOS9`, and `swift 2`. I would like to share what worked for me:

Just add this in you `ViewDidLoad` method

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false;
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to remove the gap between navigation bar and first cell writing this line of code in viewDidLoad()

```
self.tableView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
```

I tired this with Static Table Views (Style: Grouped).

Answer (score 0):

Starting in iOS 7, you automatically get a group header and some space.  Compare your app to the Settings app and you'll see.  You can work around it by telling the UITableView  to set the header height as small as possible.  See [How to hide first group header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19056428/how-to-hide-first-section-header-in-uitableview-grouped-style).

Answer (score 0):

I realize this was answered a long time ago, but for anyone else running into a similar situation, I'll share what ended up working for me:

If you're using a xib, select the top level view and set 'Status Bar' to 'None' in the Simulated Metrics area of the Attributes Inspector. Fixed my spacing issue right up.

Answer (score 0):

For me this didn't work

`self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;`

This only caused the table view to sit under the NavigationBar.

What worked for me was to go into my storyboard, and resize my tableView. It seems my tableView had a 20px gap at the top to allow for the statusBar.  I scaled it and everything lined up perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I was seeing this extra space at the top of one of my table views in a very strange situation.

After I added a `UIScrollView` as the root view of my first controller in my navigation stack, if I presented the next controller as a `Show Detail` segue, my next controller would have the space above its table view.

The solution for me was to change the segue to `Present Modally` and everything went back to normal.

The strangest part of the segue changing was that *before* I added my root view being a `UIScrollView`, my `Show Detail` segue was presenting the next controller modally. Yet *after* I added the root `UIScrollView`, the `Show Detail` segue was *pushing* on the next controller (which was not what I wanted).

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem, even setting automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets to NO. This solved for me:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section;
{
    return CGFLOAT_MIN;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

In the `UIViewController.h` iOS9 SDK have a method:

```
@property(nonatomic,assign) BOOL automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(7_0); // Defaults to YES
```

is not a property, so

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
```

should be

```
-(BOOL)automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets{   
     return NO;
}
```