# iOS 11 TableView to UIView odd space below navigation bar

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have a `UIViewController` with an embedded `UITableView`. When a cell in this table view is clicked I use `pushViewController` to push the destination controller into the navigation controller that all of these are embedded in.

The navigation item has a `UISearchBar` as a `titleView` using (in `viewDidLoad`):

```
let searchBar = UISearchBar()
searchBar.delegate = self
navigationItem.titleView = searchBar
```

When the new view controller is pushed and the new view is loaded, there's an odd gap at the bottom of the navigation bar. It seems like it's trying to retain the existing height of the navbar (which is taller due to the search bar), rather than scaling up and down during the transition which is what happens by default. Here's an example (the UIView is painted black to highlight this)

[image: example]

As you can see, when I slide back to the table view it seems to fix the second view, but then the offset for the tableview is broken.

I've tried reproducing this with a new Xcode project, but I can't. Everything just works. Obviously I don't actually want to create a new project so I would like to figure out what I've done wrong.

I think this question might be similar:

[iOS 7 UITableView: How to remove space between navigation bar and first cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19111451/ios-7-uitableview-how-to-remove-space-between-navigation-bar-and-first-cell)

But I don't want the initial navbar to be smaller in height, and I have also messed with all of the insets that have been suggested in various other questions, but none of those variations are working either.

I have IB constraints on both the tableview and the embedded scrollview in the second controller, they're all set to align to the Safe Area.

I'm guessing there's something obvious I'm missing, but I'm especially confused by the behaviour of swiping back.

Any ideas?

Comment: It seems to me to be related to how/when you set up your constraints. Do you setup some constraints manually somewhere?

Comment: @iur If by manually you mean in code then no I don't. I do have some IB constraints in several places though. I'll try removing them all and see what happens (when I get back to the code later this afternoon)

Comment: Hmm, I see. From your image it looks like the constraints are applied with a delay. Maybe your search bar messes something up. Could also be related to `contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior` of scrollviews in iOS 11.

Comment: @iur I removed *all* IB constraints from all views and played with `contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior` (assigning it to `.never` and then other variations when that didn't work). The behaviour is still present

Comment: What if you remove your search bar? It could be that setting it as a title of navbar messes up constraints. From the look of your gif it seems that your tableview is pinned to navbar bottom (possibly to safe area top) and setting title to navbar doesn't change constraints (or doesn't ask for relayout immediately) and so your tableview content is "under" the search bar. Another thing to check would be to ask navbar to relayout, call `setNeedsLayout` on it immediately after setting search bar.

Comment: BTW, I just could reproduce your issue with black view in a new project. In the first view controller on viewDidAppear I set `self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false`. I think it is not the first issue related to translucency of navbar. Try to search into that direction.

Comment: @iur Removing the search bar works but that makes complete sense to me, because now the first view nav bar isn't taller. I just tried messing around with the translucency and `setNeedsLayout` but neither fixed anything from me. Your previous comment about the view being pinned to the navbar makes sense so I'll go down that avenue and see what comes up

Comment: @iur I just "fixed" this (it seems hacky to me), see my answer

Comment: Well, I guess this one either also goes to iOS undef behaviour with navbars and translucency, or you have some other related code that somehow messes up your constraints. Anyway good that you have found your fix at least somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up "fixing" this by added a `viewWillDisappear` to my initial view controller:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    navigationController?.view.layoutSubviews()
}
```

It makes sense to me that this fixes the issue, but it seems quite hacky. I'm investigating other avenues, but since it does constitute a solution to the main problem, I'm going to answer my own question.