# Swift set constraints to container view in UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, nslayoutconstraint

I have `UITableView`, and I put container view on top as a header like this:

[image]

And everything work well.

Now I would like to hide this container header view, when tap in the cell.

My first attempt was :

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
    self.containerView.frame.size.height = 0
})
```

witch hide the view, but don't bring cells up, what it is expected and normal, because I only change frame for container view, and not for other views.

Then I try to add constraints in storyboards, but for some reason I can't set them.

Why is that? And how do I achieve to hide container view, and bring all other cells to the top.

Comment: Try changing `tableview.estimatedSectionHeaderHeight = 0`

Comment: Nop this is not helping... the results stay the same.

Comment: I'd suggest to add the header view it as another cell and hide it (as you are hiding the first cell in the table view), it should be the first cell...

Comment: once you change headerview frame height to 0 try to reasign that headerview to that table i have done same thing and its working for me

Comment: hi Prince, I didn't quite understand what you suggest. Could you please write more detailed answer.

Comment: please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19056428/how-to-hide-first-section-header-in-uitableview-grouped-style

Comment: @MarkoZadravec I have tested your issue programmatically,  i have taken a view programmatically and assigned height to 100 and after 10 second i have performed a selector which make headerviews height to 0.0.  and its working well. please check it.

Comment: @Prince Pleas see my image again. This is not real header as viewForHeaderInSection... It is container view, that is put on top of the table scroll view.

Comment: yes I know its not a headerview for each section but try to asign your view as a  table's header like tablname.tableHeaderView = yourview name

Comment: @MarkoZadravec Check my ans. It works for the container view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
            let headerView = tableView.tableHeaderView!
            headerView.setNeedsLayout()
            headerView.layoutIfNeeded()
            headerView.frame.size.height = 0
            tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView
        }
```