# How do you hide the first header element in a NSOutlineView?

Tags: macos, nsoutlineview

[image]

In the Notes-application image above you see that the first root item is not shown in a header cell. You just see a child with All Notes, how can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

I know that with UICollectionView you would generally set `setHeaderReferenceSize=CGSizeZero` within a layout delegate method or via subclassing the layout class UICollectionViewFlowLayout and setting the setHeaderReferenceSize property there.  I suggest looking at the class documentation for NSOutlineView and locate the property which determines the size of the header and adjust accordingly.

Comment: They have a 'optional func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, heightOfRowByItem item: Any) -> CGFloat' however it says in the documentation Values returned by this method should not include intercell spacing and must be greater than 0. So that won't help me.

Comment: Darn.  So, NSOutlineView inherits from NSTableView.  It sounds like another poor soul has been here before in trying to suppress a header for a single section (in this case, also the first section).  It's ObjC solution, but I'm hoping it might help conceptually or contextually.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19056428/how-to-hide-first-section-header-in-uitableview-grouped-style

Comment: They are hiding the extra pixels lol :) I could give the NSOutlineView a margin offset of -2 pixels. You would think that if Apple would use it in their applications it would be something more sufisticated.

Comment: Whattttttt?  Hahaha.  That is so hacky of them!  Reminds me vaguely of a bug in UICollectionView where we had to set `setReferenceSizeForHeader` to .00001 in order to still show a section when the section had no items.