# Table view position doesn't clip to navigation bar

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, uitableview

When I create table view with custom table view, there is empty space between Navigation Bar and the top of Table View.

It looks:
[image]

I've added constraint to as equal of the view.topAnchor.
I don't know why is this happening.

How to clip the Table View to the top?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you don’t have any header added.
If you are using a nib/storyboard checkout the ViewController design -> Select tableview -> set `Footer height` & `Header height` to 0.

If you are using code, checkout this example on how to remove the header using code - [How to hide first section header in UITableView (grouped style)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19056428/how-to-hide-first-section-header-in-uitableview-grouped-style)

By default it will take 28 that's why it shows blank on top.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0
}
```

set above code and make sure delegate method will call.

Comment: sorry here i post as answer because i can't do comment.

Comment: Thank you for the clue.
But, I created the table view programmatically.

How to set those property programmatically?

Comment: Unfortunately, your code doesn't work on mine.
I just found the workaround in your link you shared. I put this code below to my viewDidLoad and it overcomes the issue:

`tableView.tableHeaderView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: tableView.bounds.size.width, height: 0.01))`

Answer (score 0):

Try this trick, add to intere view a blank UIView... In viewDidLoad:

```
view.addSubview(UIView())
```

I ignore the reason but this breaks the link between your the UIScrollView and the nav bar... This probably solve your issue.